# javascript looping through 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to work through how to publish items from multiple arrays while first searching through the separate array elements and then return only those items which match a certain criteria. The following code does not do this yet.

```
enter code here<div id="myDiv">
<script type="text/javascript">


var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementBuId(id);

}
var title = new Array("Barbecuing in the Rain","Picnicing in the Arctic",
        "How to Saute on a Radiator", "A Real Grasshopper: Bartending with Insects",
        "Food with a Bullet:  Cooking in Camden", "Mirepoix for Dummies");
var price = new Array(18.50, 23.95, 41.95, 5.95, 13.00, 99.00);
var binding = new Array("Hardcover", "Paperback", "Hardcover", "Paperback", "Paperback", "Hardcover");
var pubYear = new Array(2002, 1975, 2004, 2006, 2001, 1997);
var NYTBestSeller = new Array(true, true, false, false, true, true)
    var seriesTitle = new Array("Food Network", "The Food Network", 
            "Culinary Shortcuts", "Sunset Libations", 
            "Food Network", "The Food Network");
var bargainBooks = ("Food Network Hot Selling Bargain Book");

for (i in title) {
    if (((price[i] <= 25 && binding[i] == "Hardcover") || 
                (price[i] <= 15 && binding[i] == "Softcover")) && (pubYear[i] >= 2000) && 
            (NYTBestSeller[i] == true) && (seriesTitle[i] == "Food Network") || (seriesTitle[i] == "The Food Network"))


        //document.write("<span color='red'>This line is red</span>");



        document.write(title[i] + "<br />");
    document.write(price[i] + "<br />");
    document.write(binding[i] + "<br />");
    document.write(pubYear[i] + "<br />");
    document.write(NYTBestSeller[i] + "<br />");
    document.write(seriesTitle[i] + "<br />" + "<hr/>");

}
</script>
```

I am searching for books that met a certain criteria and then trying to output where that book is on the page a message of Hot Selling Book in green. But I can't figure out how to make the document.write work. document.write().style.color="green" does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

document.write output text only, you have to write your own tags there (a div styled as green for example).

However I suggest you a different approach, what about an empty div with an id and then do the following:

```
document.getElementById('your-div-id').innerHTML = 'text <br /> <span style="color: green;">other text</span> and so on';
```

Will also reorganize code in a better way.

Document.write will only append code to the end of the output stream (the document in this case), so you can't specify where output will appear.

**Edit 1:**
Also, what about using objects in this case? As far as I can see, you are using arrays to emulate their behaviour:

```
var myObjArray = [
    {
        title: 'mytitle1',
        price: '10$',
        binding: 'dunno',
        pubYear: 'dunno-again',
        NYTBestSeller: true,
        seriesTitle: 'Something'
    },
    {
        ...other object data...
    }
]

document.getElementById('your-div-id').innerHTML += myObjArray[0].title + '<br />' + myObjArray[0].price;
```

Hope you can find it interesting

Comment: What about creating a new Array[] and have that be in another loop that is output within the data stream?

Comment: You can, but I thought you would like to print result, not store them in another array